# How does RLC send notification to PDCP or RRC?

Tags: 5g

According to 3GPP, 38.322:

- if `RETX_COUNT = maxRetxThreshold` (RLC) indicate to upper layers (PDCP, RRC) that max retransmission has been reached. (section 5.3.2)
- When receiving a positive acknowledgement for an RLC SDU with SN = x, the transmitting side of an AM RLC entity shall send an indication to the upper layers of successful delivery of the RLC SDU; (section 5.2.3.1)

My question:

1. How does RLC send such indication/notification?
2. If ORAN split option is used such that CU and DU are separated between PDCP and RLC, and there is F1 interface between them, then does F1 interface do anything to facilitate above indication/notification?